# IIS Custom 404 page page appends entire URL as query param

Tags: iis, web-config

I'm serving a website of static files using IIS 10, and it includes a custom 404 page. Unfortunately, when IIS shows the 404 page, it rewrites the url to include the original url as a query param, and that's super ugly.

Here's the website structure.

```
/
|-- web.config
|-- index.html
|-- about/
    |-- index.html
|-- 404/
    |-- index.html
```

So, when someone searches for a page that does not exist, I want them to be served the 404/index.html page. Here's the rules I have set inside my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/404" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This works, because IIS is showing them the 404 page, but it's appending the entire original url in a query param! I don't want that!

This `domain.com/fake-page` becomes `domain.com/404?404;domain.com:80/fake-page` which is ugly AF!! I just only want it to go to `/404` and that's it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

URL Rewrite allows Web administrators to easily build powerful rules using rewrite providers written in .NET, regular expression pattern matching, and wildcard mapping to examine information in both URLs and other HTTP headers and IIS server variables. Rules can be written to generate URLs that can be easier for users to remember, simple for search engines to index, and allow URLs to follow a consistent and canonical host name format.

Here is the reference: [Using the URL Rewrite Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module)